How to express degrees of understanding in Chinese:
How can these ideas be expressed in Chinese:

Case 1: Someone who fully understands and can derive certain theorems on their own from their thorough understanding. In English, we would simply say they understand or are well acquainted with some concept. But is there a distinction in Chinese conveying the idea that they understand a concept extremely well or thoroughly -- well enough to teach it and fully explain it?

Case 2: The inventor of the theorem whose piercing intellect has seen what no one else could previously imagine and revolutionized the understanding of a particular subject. How might you describe their understanding and mental capacity for that particular topic?


I look forward to any potential responses!
Thank you!

我简直是一头雾水，丈二和尚摸不着头脑，擀面杖吹火是一窍不通。

明白 VS. 了解

明白 means 'understand' in general


大致明白 = roughtly understand

很明白 = quite understand

深深明白 = deeply understand



了解 means 'understand' in detail

了解 something implies you know it in detail
明白航海的程序 (understand sailing procedures) is not enough, you have to 了解航海的程序 (understand sailing procedures in detail)
了解 < 很了解 <  深度了解
Edit:

Case 2 is best described as 領悟 (profoundly understand)

領悟出 --> revolutionary understanding
領悟到 --> enlightening understanding

So, I guess the case 1 person who understands well enough to tutor or teach might 了解或很了解 but the case 2 person has a 深度了解.  And a person with a casual understanding could be said to 大致明白.(?.)      好多謝!  你真係好人.

@YQ002lc2 I think 深度了解 is 100% correct but not enough for case 2. For a theorem, there can be many people who deeply understand (深度了解 or similarly, 精通, 通晓, etc.) it, but there’s just one inventor. Calling an inventor directly as 发明者/创造者 is probably the most accurate and straightforward way. 了解 and 大致明白 sound accurate in their cases respectively.

See my edition.

Allow me to introduce two friends of mine :)

王教授不但精通物理, 也很熟悉數學, 對應用力學更有着澈底/透徹/深入的瞭解 - Professor Wong is not only proficient in Physics; he also very familiar with Mathematics and has a thorough/complete/deep understanding of Applied Mechanics.

陳先生是一個傑出/卓越的科學家. 他拥有敏锐的智慧和対事物的洞悉力. - Mr. Chen is an outstanding scientist. He has a keen intelligence and the ability to grasp the inner nature of things.


